# Django on IIS (Internal Server Error)

Tags: python, django, windows, iis, server

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

C:\Python34\python.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

This is the error I'm getting. I'm using python 3.4.2 but for some reason, it still doesn't work.
I was following a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgTFrAwXeoI) and did everything exactly the way he did it. Anyone got any idea as to what is going on?

Comment: Post more details, like settings.

Comment: i just created a new project to try and upload it onto the IIS, I used IIS 9, python 3.4.2 and the latest django..... I used exactly the same settings as the guy in the video did....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to host a django project on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505814/how-to-host-a-django-project-on-iis)

Comment: I found out that fastcgi doesn't work beyond Django 1.7
Needed to find an alternate method